# mod_rewrite .html with request

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Good afternoon.

I've a URI like:

```
/index.php?page=something&option=somethingelse
```

And I've rewrited it to this:

```
checkout.html
```

with the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^checkout.html$ /index.php?page=something&option=somethingelse [L]
```

But if I need to add some parameters (for example: **?sheet=happens**) to request, its ignoring:

```
/index.php?page=something&option=somethingelse&?sheet=happens
```

Please note that I need to add parameters, starting with ? (question mark), because its generated by CMS. Thats why I write "&?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^checkout.html$ /index.php?page=something&option=somethingelse [L,QSA]
```

- `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.